# Using Fourier transform for an oscillator?

Tags: fourier-transform

I am currently having a lot of difficulty with the following question:

Consider an oscillator whose characteristic frequency is $\omega_0$  and which is excited in such a way as to give out a pulse of Gaussian shape. Its energy state is characterized by the function $E(t)=e^{f(t)}e^{iω_0 t}$ where $$f(t)=[-(t-t_0)^2/2(Δt)^2 ] e^{iω_0 t}$$
The pulse of radiation is centered at $t=t_0$ and has a spread in time of $\Delta t$. measured at the half-amplitude points of the pulse. Find the spectral $E(\omega)$ distribution of this signal. Plot $E(t)$vs $t$, and $E(\omega)$ vs $\omega$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. All I know is that I must use the Fourier transform, but I am not so sure as of how to apply it.

Comment: Do you need a closed form for this? Numerical?

Comment: I assumed that it must be numerical due to Fourier transform, but I am honestly not too sure myself.

Comment: Have you used [dft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) before?

Comment: Yes I have, and tried to use it here, but got absolutely nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using numpy's discrete Fourier transform ([dft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft)) implementation

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 # Calculates the DFT of a Gaussian pulse
 def gauss_pulse(time, f0):

     tw = 2 / f0
     t0 = 3 * tw        
     e = np.exp(-(time - t0)**2 / (2 * tw**2)) * np.exp(1j * time * 2 * np.pi * f0)

     return  np.fft.fft(e)


 # Sets the peak frequency and sampling rate
 f0 = 1e3
 fsampling = 10 * f0
 dt = 1 / fsampling
 nt = 200

 df = 1 / (nt * dt)
 freq = np.arange(nt / 2) * df
 time = np.arange(nt) * dt
```

And for plotting the pulse in frequency-domain just use

```
 pulse = gauss_pulse(f0)
 plt.plot(freq, np.log(np.abs(pulse))[ : nt / 2])
 plt.show()
```

If you want it in time-domain

```
 pulse = gauss_pulse(f0)
 plt.plot(time, np.real(np.fft.ifft(pulse)))
 plt.show()
```

You should get something like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very very helpful. :D

May I ask how a summation may be used please? Thank you so very much!

Comment: @S.Tarkheena Do you mean a summation of the values of pulse?

Comment: Yes please! I hope that I am not asking too much? Since the dft that I am familiar with involves summation.

Comment: @S.Tarkheena I see, well the idea is this: imagine a function $E(t)$, and define a set of times in which you sample $E$, in the example above these times are stored in the variable `time`, $E(t_0), E(t_1),\cdots, E(t_{N-1})$, in our example $N=$`nt`. The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of this sequence is calculated as 

$$
E(\omega_k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}E(t_n)e^{-i2\pi k n /N}
$$

and I calculate just with the line `np.fft.fft(e)`. Hope it helps